# ip tables port fwd duplicates packets

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, sles

i want to fwd the udp packets that are received on port 162 to another port.ex:8981

i have executed the following cmd

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat  -p tcp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8981
```

I see that i am recieving duplicates packets now on 8981..

could some one guide me the right way of doing it?

Also how to delete the above rule ?

TIA,
/d

Comment: `tcpdump` or it never happened.

Comment: your question says udp and your `code snippet` says tcp. which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll leave the "duplicate packets" problem until there's some more diagnostic data available, but the rule deletion is easy.

To delete an iptables rule, simply replace the `-A` with `-D`:

```
iptables -D PREROUTING -t nat  -p tcp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8981
```

If you're using `-I N` instead, you can use `iptables -D N`, but that's risky if there have been any rules inserted subsequently.

If you've *really* screwed up and don't even know what `iptables` command you ran (`bash` has command history for a reason...) then you can list all the rules in a chain like this:

```
iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING --line-numbers
```

Which will get you output like this:

```
Chain int2ext (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  192.0.2.0/24         0.0.0.0/0
3    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
4    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Then, find the `num` column entry corresponding to the rule you want to delete, and run

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING <num>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, now as pudding fox points out , i may have used tcp there in cmd..also iam not quite sure of the cmd use..is there a way to see my rule using iptables and delete it?

Comment: i only want to redirect packets on same host from port 162 to another one as i cannot open socket on port < 1024 , due to permissions problem.

Comment: question updated to provide another way of deleting rules.